# Problem in Implementing AdColony Banner Ads

Tags: android, banner-ads, adcolony, android-banner

I have a problem regarding the AdColony Banner Ad Integration in my Android Studio code.
Please help me resolve this.
I am total new to coding and made a unit converter app (kg to pounds) in android studio by watching internet tutorial.

```
E:\Kaushal\kgconvertor\app\src\main\java\com\sevenapps\kgconvertor\MainActivity.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
            AdColony.requestAdView(BANNER_ZONE_ID, listener, AdColonyAdSize.BANNER, adOptions);
                                                                                    ^
```

symbol: variable adOptions

Answer (score 0):

Replace Ad Options with AdColonyAdOptions()

now:

`AdColony.requestAdView(BANNER_ZONE_ID, listener, AdColonyAdSize.BANNER, AdColonyAdOptions());`

Answer (score 0):

```
AdColony.configure(this, APP_ID);

AdColony.requestAdView(ZONE_ID, new AdColonyAdViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestFilled(AdColonyAdView adColonyAdView) {
            if (frmBannerAdsView.getChildCount() > 0) {
                frmBannerAdsView.removeAllViews();
            }
            frmBannerAdsView.addView(adColonyAdView);
        }
    }, AdColonyAdSize.BANNER);
```

try this.